# Driving a windows command line exe programmatically

Tags: windows, command-line, wrapper, exe

I have a third party windows executable that does not take command line arguments, but requires various text to be entered at the command prompt (password etc.)

Is there an easy way to drive the text entry at the command prompt programatically so I can create a wrapper for the exe file.

Ideally I'd like to do this in C/C++ but all options will be considered.

Many thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect STDIN of the process. See  [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "expect" utility to drive programs that are written for interactive text input.

On windows, this is part of "cygwin" package that enables Unix utilities to run on windows.